# Does the sphere $x^2 + (y-2)^2 + z^2 = 1$ intersect the plane $z-x = 3$? If so, find a point in their intersection. If not explain why.

Tags: 3d, spheres, solid-geometry

> Does the sphere $x^2 + (y-2)^2 + z^2 = 1$ intersect the plane $z-x = 3$? If so, find a point in their intersection. If not explain why.

I feel like I can give a convincing answer with a rough sketch, and words, but I can not figure out how to solve the problem algebraically. If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative!

Comment: It's a plane parallel to y-axis making 45 degree angle to Z and X axis with the distance of (> 1) from y-axis. The sphere is on y axis (2, 0, 0) with radius of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If so, $$x^2+(y-2)^2+(x+3)^2=1$$ or
$$2(x^2+3x+4)+(y-2)^2=0,$$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your response! One thing I do not understand is why substituting works in the first place. Do you have any suggestion where I can look to get a better understanding how this works geometrically or conceptually?

Comment: @Ben Jenney    A common point $(x,y,z)$ of the sphere  and of the plane it's a solution of the system: $x^2+(y-2)^2+z^2=1$ and $z=x+3,$ which gives a possibility of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the translation $X=x$, $Y=y-2$, $Z=z$ then

- $x^2+(y-2)^2+z^2=1 \iff X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$
- $x-z=3 \iff X-Z=3$

then consider the circle and the line in the plane $Y=0$

- $X^2+Z^2=1$
- $X-Z=3$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric/algebraic answer. The well known formula for the distance from a point $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to a plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ is $$d=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$.

So the distance from the center of the sphere $(0,2,0)$ to the plane $x-z+3=0$ is

$$d=\frac{|1\cdot 0+0\cdot 2+(-1)\cdot 0+3|}{\sqrt{1^2+0^2+(-1)^2}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So the distance from the center of the sphere to the plane $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$ is greater than the radius of the sphere $1$. Then the sphere doesn't intersect the plane.

Comment: This is a very natural, and clever, answer! and a good formula to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. To see this notice the plane can be written at $z=x+3$. Substituting into the equation of the sphere yields:
$$ x^2 + (y-2)^2 + (x+3)^2 = 1 $$
When we expand the last term of the left hand side this gives us:
$$ 2x^2 + 6x+ (y-2)^2 = -8$$
Completing the square then gives us:
$$2\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + (y-2)^2 = -8+\frac{9}{2}= \frac{-7}{2}$$
Notice that the two terms on the righthand side are always greater than or equal to zero, but the lefthand side is negative. Thus, for the reals, there is no intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your response! this was the track I started going down, and this definitely makes me feel more confident. Not to nitpick, but wouldn't it be $9/4$ rather than $9/2$ given $3^2/2^2$

Comment: No problem! It would be, except that you have the 2 out front, so you're really adding $2\cdot (\frac{3}{2})^2$ to both sides of the equation to complete the square.